# Working with multiple Firebase projects in an Android app for Google sign-in

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-authentication

My android app is using the GCM project which is registered with application keystore SHA1. I am using the another firebase project in my app to FCM which is using the different SHA1. Now i want to integrate the Google Sign-in in my app which required the SHA1 to register for my app for google sign-in. I don't want to remove my SHA1 from GCM project for this. How can i import the another firebase project such that it don't require my SHA1 key again.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Google Sign-In component to work on Android, it requires a SHA-1 (the fingerprint of the key used to sign the APK) and package name (e.g. com.foo.bar) to be registered for the app**. This combination allows Google Sign-In to know which Google API project is being used by a particular app. **A given pair of SHA1 and Package Name is globally unique within Google (and Firebase projects),** so if you try to add the same pair SHA-1 and package name to an upgraded Firebase project, you get an error that the OAuth2 client already exists (in the Google API project) [see Image](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KR5f8-aeZ8Y/WFL_NYmnZTI/AAAAAAAAAqg/kHkHVQpA8jAV-aDOzPtbCuH3nX8dX1CvQCLcB/s1600/image01.png)
2. Warning: **If you see this, don't delete your existing client ID for
   apps in production**! **The right choice is to create a new app with
   the same your package name in the Firebase console for the upgraded
   project, but not to include a SHA1**. Now implement [Google Sign In
   with Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) as normal. At one point you will have to
   configure your Google Sign Options object:
3. **GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
            GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                 .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                 .requestEmail()
                 .build();**
4. The default_web_client_id string here is used to set the audience field of the ID token. The value comes from the google-services.json file, which is from the Firebase project rather than the Google project. You'll need to replace it with a client ID from the Google project. You can use any Web client ID, or create a new one: [see image](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GZbXmWlT0aQ/WFMCuxV8pSI/AAAAAAAAArA/nJhC2mVUt88ztFQIX3qOm3XUV3XGpeM_gCLcB/s1600/image03.png)
5. Next, back in the Firebase project, whitelist the client ID you just set for the GoogleSignInOptions in the Auth > Sign In Providers > Google section of the Firebase console. [See Image](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-yrQuefMpVPg/WFL_qBQHM1I/AAAAAAAAAqo/2dTjxfBrZhIua-1ZwKH3OovC9bcPmULSwCLcB/s1600/image02.png)
6. Be sure to re-download your google-services.json and add it to your Android app. At this point, your Firebase project will accept Google ID tokens generated by your Google project - so your Android app will happily sign in to Google using the Google project, then authenticate with your Firebase project using the Google ID token following the [normal approach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin). You'll be able to make authenticated calls to Google APIs associated with the Google API project, and authenticated calls to Firebase APIs using the Firebase project.
7. [Please find the document source for your reference](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html)

Comment: I just tried using an oauth web token (not android or ios) and it does not work. The android app keeps failing with the following error message: 
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
Any ideas?

Comment: i tried this way, bug get `error message: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. I discovered that there is actually a Google Developer Console associated with the Firebase account, which is hidden. My solution is head to Firebase Project Settings > Service accounts > Click the link under the Other service accounts: [Firebase Console Service Accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFuB7.png).

This will open up the Google Cloud Platform, you may close this page and get to your Google Developer Console, you will see a project with the exact name of your project name in your firebase shown.

You can also see OAuth 2.0 Client IDs are auto generated by Google Service.